# Cant Scrape webpage with Python Requests Library

Tags: python, html, xpath

I am trying to get some info from a webpage (link below) using Requests in python; however, the HTML data that I see in my browser doesn't seem to exist when I connect via python's request library. None of the xpath queries return any information. I am able to use requests for other sites such as amazon (the site below is actually owned by Amazon, but I can't seem to scrape any information from it).

```py
url = 'http://www.myhabit.com/#page=d&dept=men&asin=B00R5TK3SS&cAsin=B00DNNZIIK&qid=aps-0QRWKNQG094M3PZKX5ST-1429238272673&sindex=0&discovery=search&ref=qd_men_sr_1_0'
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} 
page = requests.get(url, headers=user_agent)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
query = tree.xpath("//span[@id=ourPrice]/text()")
```

Comment: Your `url` is not in quotes, therefore it isn't a string.

Comment: It seems to be loading the product description using javascript and ajax.

Comment: In fact, almost site content is built under javascript XHR calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element is generated using javascript, you can use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) to get the source, to get headless browsing combine it with [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/build.html):

```
url = 'http://www.myhabit.com/#page=d&dept=men&asin=B00R5TK3SS&cAsin=B00DNNZIIK&qid=aps-0QRWKNQG094M3PZKX5ST-1429238272673&sindex=0&discovery=search&ref=qd_men_sr_1_0'

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get(url)
_html = browser.page_source

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print(BeautifulSoup(_html).find("span",{"id":"ourPrice"}).text)
$50
```

Comment: This is great. I used exactly what you suggested except I added an executable path to the phantomjs.exe                                                   browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=path)                                 This seems to work for the most part; however sometimes it returns null and other times '$50'. What could be causing the inconsistency?

Comment: You just may need to add a wait. There are some good examples here in the docs http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html

Answer (score 0):

here is the code, how i scrap a table from one site. in that site, they didn't define id or class in table so you no need to put anything. if id or class there means just use html.xpath('//table[@id=id_val]/tr') instead of html.xpath('//table/tr')

```
from lxml import etree
import urllib
web = urllib.urlopen("http://www.yourpage.com/")
html = etree.HTML(web.read())
tr_nodes = html.xpath('//table/tr')
td_content = [tr.xpath('td') for tr in tr_nodes  if [td.text for td in tr.xpath('td')][2] == 'Chennai' or [td.text for td in tr.xpath('td')][2] == 'Across India'  or 'Chennai' in [td.text for td in tr.xpath('td')][2].split('/') ]
main_list = []
for i in td_content:
    if i[5].text == 'Freshers' or  'Freshers' in i[5].text.split('/') or  '0' in i[5].text.split(' '):
       sub_list = [td.text for td in i]
       sub_list.insert(6,'http://yourpage.com/%s'%i[6].xpath('a')[0].get('href'))
       main_list.append(sub_list)
print 'main_list',main_list
```