# Python Requests Getting HTML Code from Wrong Page

Tags: python, html, url, screen-scraping

So I started using python requests to look at the html code from some websites. I would do r = requests.get(url) to get all the information I need.

However, I noticed that this doesn't work sometimes. For example, I'm using steamcommunity.com to get some market data, so I used the url: http://steamcommunity.com/market/search. This brings up the first page of items out of over 7,000 pages. To get a different page, I used this url: http://steamcommunity.com/market/search#p4_quantity_desc. This should take you to the 4th page of the website, and it does if you put it in your browser. But, when I go to read the html code, I get the same code from both urls, even though they should point to different pages with different code.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, but shouldn't the html code still be different with the different urls? I did inspect element and checked it out in chrome and there was different html code. I'm very new to this, so if I'm making an obvious mistake please point it out. Thanks!

Comment: I got working html code from the first scrape on the first page. I was able to read all 10 items successfully exactly as they showed up in chrome. But, I'm curious. How did you know that it was mostly JavaScript? Do you have other tools besides Chrome's inspect element?

Comment: just look at the source code, If you want to scrape javascript generated elements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708484/cant-scrape-webpage-with-python-requests-library/29708974#29708974

Comment: Alright, I'll try that out. Thanks so much!

Comment: try the most basic of tools,  'curl http://steamcommunity.com/market/search#p4_quantity_desc' or wget