# urllib.open wait for the content finish to load

Tags: python, urllib

I try to crawl a website with urllib, but the problem is once browser the url, the web will shows in the main content area "wait for the result it take aournd 5 to 10 sec", after some seconds the web will receive the data and show on the main content area.  How can I get the correct content when the page is succeeded to receive data from the source. I use python 2.7 here is the code:

```
  class NewOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
        version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.10 Chromium/15.0.874.120 Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2'

nop = NewOpener()

content=""
cardata={}
try:
    page_raw = nop.open(url)
    page=page_raw.read()
    soup = bs(page)
    print soup
```

Comment: If it is generated with javascript you will be out of luck, you will be better off using something like selenium with phantomjs to get the html

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about  how to do it with selenium and phantomjs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708484/cant-scrape-webpage-with-python-requests-library/29708974#29708974 It is easy to setup with pahntomjs for headless browsing

Answer (score 0):

After `page_raw.read()` the entire content the webserver will give you for this URL is in `page`. Inside you will find a `<script>` tag which contains Javascript to load more.