# Get Image value on source page using Python or Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, google-visualization

Actually I am using google charts.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          is3D: true,
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        var imgUrl = chart.getImageURI();
        $('#piechart_3d').prepend('<img src = "'+imgUrl+'">');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

this was my html code. I can see the img src vlaue on inspect element , but not in the view source.

my python code is

```
url = 'index.html' // the above html code
content  = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = content.read()
```

while printing the data I can get only   is still empty .the image part is not loaded. How to construct the data with all those things without selenium and browser events. How to do on program. .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's not in the 'view source' but is in 'inspect element' that means it's a dynamically created element and you won't be able to get it without loading the full page using Javascript. Take a look at http://phantomjs.org/ (Node.JS) for something that can handle that.

Comment: Is that any way to get that data by using python.

Comment: yes you can use selenium

Comment: @PadraicCunningham If I use selenium this will open the browser right. the code is in server.

Comment: no you can have headless browsing using it with phantomjs

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Is there any example for this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29708974/2141635