# How to Trace Particular Content in Web Page using Python in Certain Time Period?

Tags: javascript, python, web-services, web, browser

I Want to Monitor Some Content Changes Which is Present in Some Web Pages. i Want to do the Same in Daily Basis using any Scripting or Browser plugin itself....

for example, I Want to Wet Notified if Some Changes Happened in Particular Content at Some Web Pages Based On My Query Without Subscribing their Subscription.

- I want to get notified when it matches my criteria on daily basis..
- Is their any script or browser plugin available for that?
- Can i achieve this using  python script to trace changes available...
- How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code, how i scrap a table from one site. in that site, they didn't define id or class in table so you no need to put anything. if id or class there means just use html.xpath('//table[@id=id_val]/tr') instead of html.xpath('//table/tr')

```
import time
from lxml import etree
import urllib
while True:
    time.sleep(60) # for 1 minute time interval
    #time.sleep(86400) # for 1 day time interval
    web = urllib.urlopen("http://www.yoursite.com/")
    html = etree.HTML(web.read())
    tr_nodes = html.xpath('//table/tr')
    td_content = [tr.xpath('td') for tr in tr_nodes  if [td.text for td in tr.xpath('td')][2] == 'Chennai' or [td.text for td in tr.xpath('td')][2] == 'Across India'  or 'Chennai' in [td.text for td in tr.xpath('td')][2].split('/') ]
    main_list = []
    for i in td_content:
        if i[5].text == 'Freshers' or  'Freshers' in i[5].text.split('/') or  '0' in i[5].text.split(' '):
            sub_list = [td.text for td in i]
            sub_list.insert(6,'http://yoursite.com/%s'%i[6].xpath('a')[0].get('href'))
            main_list.append(sub_list)
    print 'main_list',main_list
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this simply writing the python script based on **urllib/requests/Beautiful soup** Modules.

What you have to do is write a function to parse the required part of the website and(do the in a loop) check if it meets your requirement, if it doesn't meet then exit the loop and after some time run again the loop (you can do this using time module's time.sleep() function) and check again and again.

```
def parse(url):
    #extract the content you want
    while(#condition):
            if condition met:
                #do this
            else:
                #do this
           time.sleep(#time after that you want to recheck)
```

that's it and you are done. Don't forget to import modules! :)

Comment: thanks @Sajjan Kumar .. let me back, once i did the code.

Comment: let me know what have you got !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708484/cant-scrape-webpage-with-python-requests-library  check this link... which is done using something called webdriver using selenium and phantomjs

Comment: Yes this can be done using selenium webdriver module and a browser(mostly phantomjs). This is mostly used to automate the web-stuff and for testing purpose. and as you search more you will find other modules also. So check you module-familiarity and go ahead and write code. you can be more specific on your problem !

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed  if you get you solution then marked it as closed  or let me know lets see if i can help.

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed Where would I check ? ! :)

Comment: sorry check it now. that was deleted by some one who consider based on my previous link. now i put the code via answer

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed Ya that's great.xpath is again a saviour :) !